# I can't refresh my webview when I open push notification

Tags: java, android, webview, push-notification, push

I want to create Android app of my web site using `WebView` and gcm, I am about to finish my project. My application can receive push notifications, `WebView` is working properly but I have a problem. The problem is that I can't refresh my `WebView` when I open push notification. When the app is on background mood it can't be refreshed. It shows old view.

My **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // label to display gcm messages
    TextView lblMessage;
    Controller aController;
    private WebView webView;

    // Asyntask
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
    private Intent notificationIntent;

    public static String name;
    public static String email;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






          //Get webview 
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        startWebView("http://admob.adnet.az/main/index.php");





        //Get Global Controller Class object (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();


        // Check if Internet present
        if (!aController.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            // Internet Connection is not present
            aController.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Getting name, email from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        email = i.getStringExtra("email");      

        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

        // Make sure the manifest permissions was properly set 
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        // Register custom Broadcast receiver to show messages on activity
        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                Config.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        // Get GCM registration id
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        final String email = i.getStringExtra("email");
        // Check if regid already presents
        if (regId.equals("")) {

            // Register with GCM            
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);

        } else {

            // Device is already registered on GCM Server
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {


                // Skips registration.              
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();







            String url = "http://admob.adnet.az/main/index.php?email="+email+"&regid="+regId;






                  //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
                //When opening a url or click on link

                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
                    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                    //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }

                    //Show loader on url load
                   // public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                       // if (progressDialog == null) {
                            // in standard case YourActivity.this
                          //  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWebView.this);
                          //  progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                           // progressDialog.show();
                      //  }
                   // }
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        try{
                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            progressDialog = null;
                        }
                        }catch(Exception exception){
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }); 

                 // Javascript inabled on webview  
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

                // Other webview options
                /*
                webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
                webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                */

                /*
                 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
                 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 
                 */

                //Load url in webview
                webView.loadUrl(url);



                //new ReloadWebView(this, 5, webView);












            } else {

                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.

                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        aController.register(context, name, email, regId);

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };

                // execute AsyncTask
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }       

    private void post(String serverUrl, Map<String, String> params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void startWebView(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // Create a broadcast receiver to get message and show on screen 
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

            // Display message on the screen
            lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            aController.releaseWakeLock();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Cancel AsyncTask
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        try {
            // Unregister Broadcast Receiver
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

            //Clear internal resources.
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

My **GCMIntentService.java**:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    private Controller aController = null;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        // Call extended class Constructor GCMBaseIntentService
        super(Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        //Get Global Controller Class object (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
        if(aController == null)
           aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        aController.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device unregistred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        aController.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message from GCM server
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Create a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is your question like this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892657/how-to-reload-android-webview-after-registration-to-gcm-push-notification/14904530#14904530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    ** notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); **
    PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

**OR Add in manifest**

```
    <activity 
    android:name       = "MainActivity" 
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:launchMode = "singleTop"/>
```