# GCM with Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am Android newbie. 
I want to integrate GCM push notification with android webview. I managed to do it natively but not sure how to do it with webview.

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

java call js use WebView method:

```
public void evaluateJavascript(String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback)
```

js call java use WebView method:

```
public void addJavascriptInterface (Object object, String name)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

or you can use cordova sdk

Comment: thankyou, I will try this.

However, I thought I found a solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892657/how-to-reload-android-webview-after-registration-to-gcm-push-notification?rq=1

But this uses GCMRegistrar which is deprecated